# Benefit of using Vector2 data type over separate x & y variables

Tags: vector, data-structure, linear-algebra

I'm really curious about why a lot of people and game engines use Vector2 as its coordinate system instead of the traditional x and y value.

Is there any benefit to this?

I feel like it's just slow me down and barely has any benefit other than organizing your code.

Comment: In what way has it slowed you down? Out of curiosity.

Comment: @Aethenosity something like, Object.x += 1 should be done with Object.pos += Vector2(1, 0). or some functions only accept Vector2 too, like for example drawing a rectangle in some game engines require you to use Vector2, draw_rect(Vector2(x, y), Vector2(width, height)) without Vector2, you can do things faster, like draw_rect(x, y, width, height). It organizes your code by sacrificing the speed of writing the code, and there is nothing you can do about it, you cant shorten it by using something like Vec2 = Vector2, it will cause errors

Comment: Honestly, anything that has "barely any benefit other than organizing your code" already seems immensely useful to me.

Comment: @Nax, yeah.. but it should be optional, you can even create your own Vector2 system in any language, it just annoys me imo.

Comment: On the other hand, writing `Object.pos += Object.mov;` is significantly faster and easier than `Object.x += Object.movX; Object.y += Object.movY;`

Comment: Nothing prevents you from writing an inline function that takes separate parameters for convenience constructing the two Vector2 for you.
But from experience in practice you actually save time using Vector2 once your system gets complex like managing relative objects: `render_pos = object->pos; object = object->parent; while(object) { render_pos += object->pos; object=object->parent; }` Saves you a lot of writing on the long run.

Comment: If *typing* has any significant contribution to "things that slow you down," then either you're not spending enough time reasoning about your code or your problems are beyond trivial. The things that slow you down in real world problems are working out the logic and tracking down the causes of errors/bugs that don't have a useful message. In those things, good organization is *golden*.

Comment: Why do we use `int` instead of just 32 `bool`s? Because it's way more convenient.

Comment: @jpmc26 I didn't find anything that would make me think "a senior developer with 5+ years experience". He seems to not even be using an IDE yet and the whole question is about him still wondering why data is structured into sensible data types. I'll assume that you adhere to the "be nice" policy and just severely misjudged OPs skill level, because telling a beginner "_you're not spending enough time reasoning about your code or your problems are beyond trivial_" is just not nice.

Comment: @R.Schmitz What would be most "not nice" here is letting an inexperienced developer continue to think that typing is a problem they should ever spend time worrying about. It's *cruel* to deny someone the opportunity to reorient their thinking when they have such a harmful misconception. My statement is true. The unmentioned possibility is that the OP is overestimating the contribution of typing to their development time (In other words, the antecedent is false.), but I thought this went without saying since the other two options are so absurd.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have 7 years experience and I definitely worry about typing. That's why I use an IDE and other helpers to make typing the least of my time spent on a solution. I hardly believe you're coding in notepad either. I'm also not _denying_ anything, no need to get defensive and throw around "clever" words. **Your statement is true in a general sense, but it's better at showing off your skills than it is at helping.** "You're bad at this" is not _constructive_ criticism, especially for beginners.

Comment: @R.Schmitz I frequently script in Notepad++, and I still don't worry about typing. Your IDE doesn't save you typing; it reduces name look ups, which I still don't find to be a big problem but understand the desire to avoid. My statement tells the OP both how absurd it is to worry about typing (and understanding it's ridiculous is important) and two things they should focus should on instead. It's absolutely constructive, even though I chose harsh words to get the appropriate emphasis. And yes, you are denying them the chance to improve, by refusing to point out a major error in their thinking.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Your IDE doesn't save you typing" _What_? Are you sure you're really using an IDE? _Easily_ less than half of my code is actually typed in, most of it is generated by the IDE through shortcuts etc. How it is constructive to tell somebody to do architecture when they're still struggling understanding what a a single brick does is also beyond me. And your definition of "denying" is also _questionable_ at best, but hey, you're not going to see these points with me telling you so... eh. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 38):

First of all, it's way less clutter. If you have a position, a velocity and an acceleration, that's already 6 variables you have to deal with, 9 in 3d.

Secondly, and this is the most important part, it grants you access to many ways to use or change them. For instance, getting the length of the vector, normalizing it, adding them together, dot product, cross product in 3d, etc. It's possible to do this using separate variables too, but it's much easier using vectors and follows the DRY principle much better.

As for slowing you down, I'm not sure why this would do that. Apart from having to create a new Vector instead of just 2 variables, you only have to pay attention to using vector.x and vector.y, which shouldn't be that hard and isn't much worse, than vectorX and vectorY

Comment: In languages which support transparent structure types, a structure declaration can generally be processed at the machine level in a way that's at least as efficient as two separate int or float declarations.  In languages that don't support such types, however, encapsulating pairs of numbers in class objects will impose a cost that might have been avoided by handling the numbers separately.

Comment: @supercat on the other hand many computers can do vector arithmetics, which speed up the calculations 2, 3 or even 4 fold depending on the amount of coordinates

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78546/discussion-on-answer-by-balint-benefit-of-using-vector2-data-type-over-separate).

Answer (score 14):

Compare the function signatures of both `RotatePoints` versions.

Lone variables:

```
void RotatePoints(
   float *out_x, 
   int x_interleave_out,
   const float *in_x, 
   int x_interleave_in,
   float *out_y, 
   int y_interleave_out, 
   const float *in_y, 
   int y_interleave_in,
   float angle, 
   int count
) 
{
  float s = sinf(angle);
  float c = cosf(angle);

  while(count--){
    *out_x = *in_x * c + *in_y * -s;
    *out_y = *in_x * s + *in_y * c;
    out_x += x_interleave_out;
    out_y += y_interleave_out;
    in_x += x_interleave_in;
    in_x += y_interleave_in;
  }
}
```

Compared to using structures/classes:

```
void RotatePoints(
  Vector2 *out, 
  const Vector2 *in, 
  float angle, 
  int count)
{
   Matrix2x2 rotation;
   rotation.SetRotation(angle);

   while(count--){
     *out++ = *in++ * rotation;
   }
}
```

You need to tell the first version if your x and y arrays are interleaved or separate:

```
float all_together[200]; // x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2...
```

Or:

```
float x[100];
float y[100];
```

It's a lot less messy to just have a Vector2 array and pass that and the inner code is more readable too.

And the more complex the math the messier and hairier it gets if you're not using Vector and Matrix classes;

Comment: This code seems _a little_ more advanced than the skill level of the question. You're even bringing pointers into this and are using... 8(?) params for something which is supposed to be the same as 2 Vector2s?

Comment: Because it hits you **only once you hit advanced problems**. Using separate variable is short-term simpler. But when you hit advanced topics that's where it becomes unmaintainable.

Comment: Oh yeah that's exactly the gist of my answer, but I feel like you don't have to go _that_ advanced to demonstrate that. I mean, I have 7 years of programming experience, but only very little with C/C++ and I don't understand what's going on here. OP was talking about ints x and y vs Vector2, but I have no idea which is the _real_ x and y in your first example.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Plus, he may not know c at all. E.g. in Unity, you're not programming with c/c++, you just work with references (Hope that was the point of them in this code :D). The loop structure maybe not that understandable for a programer, that doesn't know c, too. (As an example)

Answer (score 11):

## Readability > Writeability

> I feel like it's just slow me down and barely has any benefit other
>   than organizing your code.

You are correct in that it (slightly) slows you down writing *that* code. However, you write it once in the beginning and from then on *everytime* you come back you are going to read it. So optimizing the reading speed will do much more good that optimizing the writing speed.

## Naming things

Now, you might have difficulties seeing how `draw_rect(Vector2(x, y), Vector2(width, height))` is supposed to be more readable than `draw_rect(x, y, width, height)`, but to be honest, they both aren't as readable as they could be.

Look at this pseudocode:

```
position = Vector2(x, y)
size = Vector2(width, height)
draw_rect(position, size)
```

Yes, this takes 2 lines more and in the beginning I also thought that was bad. It isn't though.
Giving things names makes this take less brain power to read, which you will be very thankful for as soon as the program gets more complex. *Especially* when you're debugging it. Naming things well will also improve other things and make you faster in the long run.

## The still very short, but slightly longer run

You mentioned 
`Object.x += 1` vs `Object.pos += Vector2(1, 0)`
Again you're right, your way is faster for this (a single line). But let's just look at a minimally more complex class, you can have:

```
position;
velocity;

void UpdatePosition(){
    position += velocity;
}
```

Compare with:

```
xPosition;
yPosition;
xVelocity;
yVelocity;


void UpdatePosition(){
    xPosition += xVelocity;
    yPosition += xVelocity;
}
```

That is faster to read *and* to write. By the way, with such a small example it's not suuuper hidden, but did you notice the typo in the second version? That's easy to overlook, especially if the class is more complex than this unrealistically small example (There's a theme here...). It's one bug that *can't* happen when using Vector2.

## IDEs

> you cant shorten it by using something like Vec2 = Vector2

You might be working on a school assignment where you aren't allowed to use an IDE.
If you don't, use one and look up the autocomplete shortcut (most of the time it's Ctrl+Space).

Then you can write "Vec" and use that shortcut and the IDE will show you a list of all classes that start with "Vec". I don't think any professional coder works without this, because this is so much faster. The alternative is to learn *every class* by heart, with correct typing down to the single character. Ain't nobody got time for that, especially in the business world where time is money.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your "update position" method. It should be yPosition += yVelocity right? Rather than yPosition += xVelocity?

Comment: "You are correct in that it (slightly) slows you down writing that code." This is patently untrue in any application where things move in more than one direction. Writing code that transforms a coordinate or vector in multiple dimensions would be vastly harder to write.

Comment: And if you can't use autocomplete then don't call your vector type Vector2 to start with, call it vec2, or just vec if you have a primarily 2D game.

Comment: @Aethenosity Exactly, something like that can happen easily while typing or copy-pasting, especially if you're keeping other things in mind while doing that.

Comment: @jpmc26 If you look at the examples OP gave (or first line under "The still very short, but slightly longer run" in this answer), there is more code to write in the Vector2 version. Which will take longer. That why I wrote "_that_ code" and then gave an example how it will be faster to write in other places. You did read more than the first paragraph before you judged, right?

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't mention that you don't even need to do `object.pos += Vector2(1, 0)` (at least, outside of C#, if `Vector2` is a struct) because you can just do `object.pos.x += 1`.

Comment: @NicHartley Because you lose the context a Vector2 gives you. Even if only one value changes I'd still prefer `Vector2 oneStepRight = Vector2(1,0)`. A Vector2 just... _feels right_, that _is_ a movement (or size, velocity etc) in 2-dimensional space. As a result, when I want to concentrate on game mechanics, I don't have to care about floats or doubles or ints or the amount of dimensions, I just have to do `position += oneStepRight`.

Answer (score 8):

Operator overloading.

```
Vector v3 = v2 + v1;
```

There is now only one place in your code where you have to write, test and debug vector addition, as opposed to tens, hundreds or thousands.

Obviously vector addition is an overly simplistic example, but there are more complex vector operations and the same applies to those too.

Answer (score 2):

Using structures & classes in place of a pile of primitive variables allows us to focus more of our attention on the higher levels of problem solving.

As taken from Code Complete:

> **Reduce Complexity** - A primary goal of software design and construction
>   is conquering complexity. The motivation behind many programming
>   practices is to reduce a program’s complexity, and reducing complexity
>   is arguably the most important key to being an effective programmer.
>
> **Program in Terms of the Problem Domain** - Another specific method of
>   dealing with complexity is to work at the highest possible level of
>   abstraction. One way of working at a high level of abstraction is to
>   work in terms of the programming problem rather than the computer
>   science solution.

Using a vector class / struct plays to both these points.

Answer (score 1):

The same reasons that [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) is a code smell apply to using a vector instead of separate variables. Vector2D/3D is just a special case of avoiding primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically a vector is *a point in a vector space*. That's something with real physical relevance – the space we live in is basically a vector space.

**The individual components** `x` **and** `y` **are not**. They depend on a choice of coordinate frame, and generally there is no clear reason why some particular coordinate frame should be used. It's an *implementation detail*, so it's best encapsulated in an opaque type. Indeed, you'll mostly access individual components in very simple applications like 2D platformers, but in anything with somewhat serious physics handling you'll much more typically have offsets pointing in some direction that's unrelated to the coordinate axes. Doing that with coordinates would *always* require basically duplicating each calculation.